# Ruby on Rails Active Record return value when create fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am new to ruby on rails and having trouble getting this work. Basically I have a user registration page which has a password confirmation. In the User class I have the following validation:

```
validates :password, confirmation: true
```

And in the controller I have

```
def create
    vals = params[:user]
    if(User.exists(vals[:username])) 
        flash[:warning] = "#{vals[:username]} already exists! Please try a new one. "
    else
        vals[:create_date] = DateTime.current
        user = User.create(vals, :without_protection => :true)
        if user==false or user==nil or user==vals
            flash[:warning] = "#{vals[:username]} has not been registered successfully. "
        else
            flash[:notice] = "#{vals[:username]} has been registered. "
        end
    end
    redirect_to users_path
end
```

The problem is that when the password does match the confirmation, I am still getting the notice message showing that the registration is successful. As you can see I have tried several return values for `create` but none of them seems to succeed. I am pretty sure that the validation is working because I cannot see the user that I just created if password does not match with confirmation. In addition, when I use `create!`, I can see the website crashes with the validation error. Can anyone help telling me what `create` should return when the record is not validated?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the :without_protection parameter do?

Comment: It is here to allow mass-assignment. I don't think this interferes with validation.

Comment: Do you mean that when the password does NOT match the confirmation, you still get the successful message? Because the other way should be the correct functionality.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The answer to your question is, `User.create` returns a `User` instance if it succeeds *or* fails. If it fails because of validations, the instance will be invalid and will have errors:

```
user.valid? # <= returns false
user.errors.count # <= will be > 0
user.errors.blank? # <= will be false
```

So your code would change from this:

```
if user==false or user==nil or user==vals
```

to this:

```
if !user.valid?
```

You can also use this pattern:

```
user.attributes = vals
if user.save
   ... save succeeded ...
else
   ... save failed ...
end
```

The `save` method returns a boolean `true` or `false` since you are calling it on an existing instance.

But lets get you on the right track in a few other ways:

**First:** you have this:

```
if User.exists(vals[:username])
```

(I'm assuming `exits` is a method you put on your `User` model because that's not a Rails thing). Instead of doing that check in your controller, you can just use another validation on the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   validates :username, unique: true
   ...
end
```

Now when you try to create the user, it will fail validation if you already have one with that name.

**Second:** You have this:

```
vals[:create_date] = DateTime.current
```

This is unnecessary. If you add a column to your model called `created_at` it will hold the creation date automatically (managed by ActiveRecord). You can add this, and its partner `updated_at` to your model in your migration like this:

```
create_table :users do |t|
   ...
   t.timestamps # <= tells rails to add created_at and updated_at
end
```

Or, since you already have a `users` table:

```
add_column :users, :created_at, :datetime
add_column :users, :updated_at, :datetime
```

Now you will always have the date/time of creation and last update on your user model with no need for additional code.

**Third:** You have this:

```
user = User.create(vals, :without_protection => :true)
```

Don't do this. Instead, change this:

```
vals = params[:user]
```

To this:

```
vals = params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

And then keep protection on:

```
user = User.create(vals)
```

You can add any additional columns you want to bring from your form to the `permit()` call. This is very important because it is hard to fix this kind of thing later. "If once you go down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny."

**Fourth:** You should not redirect to the `user_path` if the save failed, because there will be no user model to show. Instead you should re-render your `new` form. You also don't need flash messages for the errors. If the `new` form renders, it can check `@user.errors` and report error messages accordingly. See the [ActiveRecord error object documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

**Finally:** You mention that you your validation fails even when your password is properly confirmed. I can't say for sure without seeing your form code, but make sure your password field is called `password` and the confirmation field is called `password_confirmation`. Rails looks for this `*_confirmation` field value specifically when validating for confirmation.

If that doesn't do it, post your form code and I'll revise.

Comment: One more thing to complement:
If is possible try to raise an exception if something went wrong, is a good way stop the process and return a error message.

Comment: The `#valid?` method will query the database for validity; `user.errors.blank?` may return true if you forgot to record the error in custom validation (didn't verify this).

Comment: What is going to happen (in general case) if there is an issue with some database permissions? I feel like `#create` is going to raise some exception.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is the **`ActiveRecord object`**. The official source code shows that `create` return the object if it succeeds or fails:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb, line 29
def create(attributes = nil, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, &block)
    object.save
    object
  end
end
```

**How to judge it succeeds or fails**

The real answer is **`persisted?`**:

```
if user.persisted?
  # Success
else
  # Failed
end
```

Why didn't use `user.valid?` to do it? Because sometimes it is not enough when there are some callbacks which operate other models failed:

```
class One < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twos
  after_create :create_twos_after_create
  def create_twos_after_create
    # Use bang method in callbacks, than it will rollback while create  two failed 
    twos.create!({})    # This will fail because lack of the column `number`
  end
end

class Two < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :number, presence: true
end
```

Now, we execute `One.create` will fail, check the log file, it will be a rollback because it failed to create two. In this case, `One.create.valid?` still return `true`, but it actually created failed, so use `One.create.persisted?` to replace it is necessary.

Notice: The code is tested in Rails 5.1.