# Return true/false on creation of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean, creation

When saving and updating an object, the return value is of boolean type - `true` or `false`.

As the `create` method returns the object as a value, how can I find out if a creation failed or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Active Record return value when create fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975835/ruby-on-rails-active-record-return-value-when-create-fails)

Comment: Thanks. And the response to your deleted comment: I get `false` when comparing `nil` to the variable saving the return value (of a failed creation).

Comment: Yes, sorry, my first comment was incorrect, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
@object = Blah.create()
@object.persisted? # true or false
```

also if you want to throw an error instead you could use the bang version, be sure to use rescue

```
@object = Blah.create!()
```

Comment: What would the difference be between using `valid?` and `persisted?`

Comment: `valid` checks if the object is valid or not, but `persisted` checks if it's saved or not, an object could be persisted but not valid, either by adding validators later on after the object is saved, or by saving with validation skip `@object.save(validate: false)`